# Get input variable after it is filled then do ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a checkout form where a zipcode is needed. I need this zipcode to get a LocationID. The zipcodes are in 0000XX format but i just need the first 4 digits. Now i have made a (global) javascript to get the locationID trough ajax.

The only problem is that now im using a keyup function that is activated when someone types in a zipcode. But i want it to be activated when a user has typed in something and clicks on another field. how can i do this ?

```
$('#deliveryzip').bind('keyup change', function(){

    //Get zip
    var zip = $('#deliveryzip').val();

    //Strip first 4 chars from input
    //check if 4 chars are integer
    //if all ok do ajax...

    //Get locationID from zipcode
    $.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{"zip":zip,"action":"getLocInfo"},function(response){
        if(response == "ok"){
            alert(response);

            //If return is ok..
            var show = true;
        }
    });    


if(show){
    $('#locInfo').show();
} else {
    $('#locInfo').hide();
}
    return false;

 });
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, just use different events for different functionalities i.e.

"keyup" for validation
"change" for ajax
don't combine both in one.

Comment: you can bind onblur event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listening to the keyup event, why don't you just listen to the change event?

```
$('#deliveryzip').on('change', function(){....});
```

The change event fires when an input field changed and once it looses focus (e.g. through the user clicking on another element). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536912(v=vs.85).aspx for more info (from Microsof) and here the documentation from Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change

Answer (score 0):

You can use onBlur function : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

Onblur is most often used with form validation code (e.g. when the user leaves a form field).

Tip: The onblur event is the opposite of the onfocus event.

With jQuery : on( "blur", handler )

Comment: Using onBlur might not ber the best solution, because the obtained location shouldn't only be showed when the focus is lost (the user clicks anywhere elöse outside the control) but just when the user finishes his input, so the onChange event seems to be more suitable

Comment: voted up.. was going for the onBlur, but did not thought about this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change `'keyup change'` to `blur`

Blur is essentially the opposite of `focus`

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur)